# Integration with exponential function

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am trying to do the following integration, but not getting any lead. Also, MATHEMATICA and MATLAB are unable to symbolically integrate it.
Can we simply the integrand further? $\frac{\gamma}{x}\in (0,100)$; thus, I cannot use Taylor series expansion of $\exp{\frac{\gamma}{x}}$.
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\alpha(\beta-x)-x\exp{\frac{\gamma}{x}}}
$$

Here, $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are constants.
I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Usually, rational functions involving $x\exp(1/x)$ cannot be integrated. What makes you think that a "closed form" exists?

Comment: You really should add more context: what do you want? A closed expression is not likely. Numerically, you could hope to integrate that, but not as an indefinte integral. Moreover, your integration interval should not include values of $x$ where the denominator vanishes.

Comment: @FrankW I am wondering if the integral can come in form of an exponential integral (Ei(x)) since, in the integrand, $\alpha=0$ and/or $\beta=x$, makes the integrand an exponential integral.

Comment: @wasn'tme I want an expression involving $x$ from this integral. That's why I'm not doing definite integration here.